# How to Set InputView with ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
self.view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KeyboardView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
self.inputView = (UIInputView*)self.view;
```

Above code is for setting Nib file to Inputview, That is working, But below code is not working ...

```
NewViewController * myViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Keyboard"  bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewView"];
self.view = myViewController.view;

self.inputView = (UIInputView*)self.view;
```

Comment: your myViewController  object is just created it is not pushed show the subviews of that controller is not yet initialize.

Answer (score 0):

Please check storyboard name. It's "Keyboard" or something different. You have write bundle is `nil` but it should be `[NSBundle mainBundle]`.

```
NewViewController * myViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Keyboard"  bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewView"];
```

Check this:

```
NewViewController *vc =[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                               bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewView"];
```